The sniper shooting across the river in the city
I'm looking for an English language movie from the 90s or 00s about a sniper shooting across a river in a city.
I can remember that the scene of investigation was on the parking garage. Some important role has the parkomat which was paid or not. I can also remember that the shooter was shooting over the river to the people who were walking along rock-type stairs of some big building. On first glance there was no motive for the police why the person was the target of the shooter.

All the elements you describe are present in the movie Jack Reacher (based on the Lee Child novel One Shot) except the date: Jack Reacher was released in 2012.
The setup for the movie is an apparently random shooting, from a parking garage, across a river to an embankment which has a public staircase down which some of the victims walked. An ex-military sniper was blamed for the shooting and the movie follows Jack Reacher as he unravels the truth. One of the clues that reveals the fact that the sniper was set up was a coin with his fingerprints used to pay for parking in the multi-story car park.
